# Hide DIV Not Working

Tags: html, css

Please help!

I am trying to hide two DIV's according to media sizes here: `www.idxforrealestate.com`

I want to hide `video_home` when media is `max width 480px`, and display `photo_home` instead.

Why is this not working?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```css
#photo_home, #video_home {display: none;}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #photo_home {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  #video_home {
    display: block;
  }
}
```